# How to extract words with a repeated letter not count one specific? python

Tags: python, string, loops, file, letter

I have a multiple word file where the same letters appear multiple times. I've already learned to catch these words.

Now I would like the words with the letter "a" not to be counted by the script.

My file.txt:

```
abac
test
testtest
dog
cat
one
doog
helo
hello
abaa
abba
```

my code:

```
li = []
for string in open("test.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    count = 0
    for qq in range(0, len(string)):
        if count == 1:
            break
        for zz in range(qq + 1, len(string)):
            if string[qq] == string[zz]:
                count = 1
            if count == 1:
                li.append(string.replace("\n", ""))
                break
print(li)
```

result:

```
['test', 'testtest', 'doog', 'hello', 'abaa', 'abba']
```

I try to make that only "a" can repeat in a word, if "a" is repeated and another letter, this word is to be extracted

Expects to not recognize the word "abaa" as a result
Because, in this word, only "a" is repeated. No other letter repeated.

If the "a" and another letter are repeated then the word is to be extracted in this case

Comment: What is the output of your current code? What is your expected output?

Comment: I have given the current result.
It is expected that "abaa" should not be recognized. Since there is only an "a" repeating itself, no other letter does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to catch repeated **a** then `if` it out!

```
if string[qq] == string[zz] and string[qq] and string[qq] != "a":
    count = 1

print(li)
```

But if you don't mind, your program could be improved.

Firstly, `and string[qq]` has no effect - for normal letters it always evaluates to `True`

Secondly, your `count` (unless you plan to extend the program to allow different number of counts) could be a boolean,

```
letter_repeated = False
if (...):
    letter_repeated = True
```

And as a bonus, you have a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in python which generally do what you want:

```
li = []
max_count = 1
for string in open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8"):
    c = Counter(string) # you can modify that counter by e.g removing "a"
    if c.most_common(1)[0][1] > max_count:
        li.append(string.replace("\n", ""))

print(li)
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice it. It was that simple. I'm ashamed. Thank you for your help and for pointing out important ways to improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just skip over any instance of `"a"` in the first loop, as we don't care if the `"a"`s repeat.

```
li = []
for string in open("test.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    count = 0
    for qq in range(0, len(string)):
        if count == 1:
            break
        if string[qq] != "a":
          for zz in range(qq + 1, len(string)):
              if string[qq] == string[zz]:
                  count = 1
              if count == 1:
                  li.append(string.replace("\n", ""))
                  break
print(li)
```

Note: I saw that edit just now, your output is different it now includes "abac" as it should. However the code above obviously doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object that would be useful here

```py
from collections import Counter
words = '''
abac
test
testtest
dog
cat
one
doog
helo
hello
abaa
abba
'''
li = []
for word in words.split():
    letter_count = Counter(word.strip())
    if letter_count['a'] == 1:
        li.append(word.strip())
    else:
        del letter_count['a'] # remove a from counter
        if sum(letter_count.values()) > len(set(word.strip())) - 1: #This means something is repeating
            li.append(word.strip())
```

**Output**

```
['test', 'testtest', 'dog', 'cat', 'one', 'doog', 'helo', 'hello', 'abba']
```

Comment: I'm using this elsewhere in the code. I tried this way and it didn't work for me.
But I will look at it for the future, I like this way because there aren't many loops. Thank you